# Creating and validating JWT token in asp net core MVC application (which does not have client server approach)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jwt

I have seen many examples to generate and validate JWT token in WEP API.

WEP API will have client and server approach. Hence we will validate user and generate JWT token in server and send to client. Client will store the token in browser memory next time through httpclient token will attached in request header and send it again to server. Now server will validate those token before hitting controller and allow to access those resource.

But in MVC application we don't have client and server approach. it will send view pages as result to browser.

My question is in MVC controller I have validated the user and created JWT token,

1. Now how to store the token in client
2. How to attach the token in request header.
3. Where should I do the token validation logic in MVC.
4. Where should I do the refresh token logic in MVC.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, here are several solutions.

1. Store token in cookie, this is the recommended practice. Example:

   ```
        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(config=>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "auth";
            })
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                //...
            };
        });
   ```

*Although the backend can serialize the token and send it to the view (using JavaScript to store the token in Localstorage), this is not safe. Cookie can  avoid csrf attacks. It is suitable for single page application.*

2. If you put it in LocalStorage or SessionStorage, you need to get the token first and put it in the header of the request (take ajax as an exmple). Otherwise, no other configuration is required.

```
      beforeSend: function(request) {
          request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", sessionStorage.getItem("Authorization"));
      }
```

3. You need to add `[Authorize]` to some actions, it will trigger this authentication which you configed in service. Or you can add a action to parse the tocken to get the context.
4. When someone update own information, you can regenerate a tocken and then send it to view to update the LocalStorage or cookie. It will carry this token in the next request.

*The view can send a request to authenticate.*

```
public IActionResult Authenticate()
    {
        //...
        var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        Response.Cookies.Append("authname", tokenString);
        return View("index");
    }
```

*In startup (ConfigureServices), you can config the getting method with cookie.*

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
            .AddCookie(config=>
            {
                config.Cookie.Name = "authname";
            })
  .AddJwtBearer(o =>
  {
   o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
   {
       //get cookie value
       OnMessageReceived = context =>
       {
           var a = "";
           context.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("authname", out a);
           context.Token = a;
           return Task.CompletedTask;
       }
   };
   o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
   {
       NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
       RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,

       ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5200",
       ValidAudience = "api",
       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("this is a long key------------------------"))
       //...
    };
 });
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. is it possible to add the token in refresh header without ajax call and where i need to check the token is expired and issue a new token. is it from any middleware or how?

Comment: Yes, you can add the token in refresh header without ajax call. The server will automatically verifies according to the middleware. You can customize a middleware to parse the token and compare the expiration time. A better solution is that the view initiates a request, and the backend verifies whether the token has expired; if it expires, the view initiates a token refresh request.

Comment: Is there any sample available to add the token in request header. and JWT MVC sample without web api and ajax

Comment: This [link](https://medium.com/@vaibhavrb999/jwt-authentication-authorization-in-net-core-3-1-e762a7abe00a) can help you. And the mehod of setting cookie I have updated in this answer.